# javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jpa, nullpointerexception

Galera, vocês são minha última salvação. Recebo esse erro `javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException` quando tento cadastrar um cliente. Minha experiencia com desenvolvimento é pouca, estou desenvolvendo esse pequeno sistema como trabalho de faculdade.

Stack Trace:

```
    javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at bean.JPAUtil.getEntityManager(JPAUtil.java:22)
    at bean.ClienteBean.salva(ClienteBean.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
```

classe bean:

```
package bean;

import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import model.Cliente;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ClienteBean {

private Cliente cliente;
private List<Cliente> clientes;

public ClienteBean() {
    cliente = new Cliente();
}

public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public List<Cliente> getClientes() {
    if (this.clientes == null) {
        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        Query a = em.createQuery("select a from Cliente a",
                Cliente.class);
        this.clientes = a.getResultList();
        em.close();
    }

    return clientes;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
public String salva() {

    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        // Verifica se o cliente ainda não está salva no banco de dados.
        if (cliente.getId() == null) {
            //Salva os dados do cliente.
            em.persist(cliente);
        } else {
            //Atualiza os dados da pessoa.
            cliente = em.merge(cliente);
        }
        // Finaliza a transação.
        em.getTransaction().commit();

    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

    this.clientes = null;
    return "index";
}

public void excluir(Cliente cliente) {

    EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    cliente = em.merge(cliente);
    em.remove(cliente);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

    this.clientes = null;

}

public String alterar(Cliente a) {
    this.cliente = a;
    return "cadastro";
}

public String cadastrarNovo() {
    cliente = new Cliente();
    return "cadastro";
}
}
```

JPAUtil:

```
package bean;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class JPAUtil {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory 
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EcommercePulsePU");

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public static void fechaEntityManager() {
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

persistence.xml, configurado para criar as tabelas (não criadas ainda)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="EcommercePulsePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/ecommercePG</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Página de cadastro Primefaces JSF:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <h:head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/css/ecommerceCSS.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/css/main.css"/>
        <title>Química Pulse</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body styleClass="body">


        <p:layout fullPage="true">

            <div id="page">

                <div id="header">
                    <ui:insert name="header" >
                        <ui:include src="/template/menusuperior.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>
                </div>
            </div>



            <p:layoutUnit position="center" size="300" >
                <div style="background-color: #1E86A6;">


                    <h:form style="color: white; border: #1E86A6; border-width: 20pt; border-style: solid;">                       

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                                <p:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" />
                                <h:inputText styleClass="col-md-3 form-control" id="nome" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.nome}" title="Nome" required="true"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
                                <p:outputLabel for="cpf" value="CPF:" />
                                <h:inputText  styleClass="col-md-3 form-control" id="cpf" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.cpf}" title="CPF" required="true"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                                <p:outputLabel for="email" value="Email:" />
                                <h:inputText  styleClass="col-md-3 form-control" id="email" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.email}" title="E-mail" required="true"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                                <p:outputLabel for="rua" value="Rua:" />
                                <h:inputText  styleClass="col-md-3 form-control" id="rua" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.rua}" title="Rua" required="true"/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
                                <p:outputLabel for="numero" value="Nº:" />
                                <h:inputText  styleClass="col-md-3 form-control" id="numero" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.numero}" title="Numero" required="true"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                                <p:outputLabel for="cidade" value="Cidade:" />
                                <h:inputText  styleClass="col-md-3 form-control" id="cidade" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.cidade}" title="Cidade" required="true"/>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                                <p:outputLabel for="pais" value="País:" />
                                <h:inputText  styleClass="col-md-3 form-control" id="pais" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.pais}" title="Pais" required="true"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                                <p:outputLabel for="cep" value="CEP:" />
                                <h:inputText  styleClass="col-md-3 form-control" id="cep" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.cep}" title="CEP" required="true"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                                <h:outputLabel  value="Telefone: " for="telefone" />
                                <h:inputText class="col-md-3 form-control" id="telefone" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.telefone}" title="Telefone" required="true"/>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                                <h:outputLabel  value="Usuário: " for="usuario" />
                                <h:inputText class="col-md-3 form-control" id="usuario" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.usuario}" title="Usuario" required="true"/>
                            </div>     

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                                <h:outputLabel  value="Senha: " for="senha" />
                                <p:password styleClass="col-md-3 form-control" id="senha" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.senha}" feedback="true" required="true"/>
                            </div></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                                <h:outputLabel  value="Confirmar Senha: " for="confirmasenha" />
                                <p:password styleClass="col-md-3 form-control" id="confirmasenha"  value="#{clienteBean.cliente.confirmasenha}" title="Confirmar Senha" required="true"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>

                        <div>
                            <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-success" value="Cadastrar" action="#{clienteBean.salva}"/>
                        </div>


                    </h:form></div>
            </p:layoutUnit>



        </p:layout>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Bibliotecas do projeto:

[image: Bibliotecas do projeto]

Desde já agradeço aos que puderem me ajudar.
Obrigado!

Comment: Qual é a versão do Java? Quais são os pacotes que você está colocando em seu classpath e/ou modulepath?

Comment: Poste o código da página. Outra coisa: em dois métodos você faz `this.cliente = null;`. Não faça isso. Isso te proporciona uma forma muito fácil de receber uma `NullPointerException`. Por exemplo: Se você invocar o método `salva()` duas vezes em sequência, na segunda vez receberá uma NPE na linha `if (cliente.getId() == null)`.

Comment: Como você recomenda que eu coloque? Obrigado pela resposta